# Initialize std::unique_ptr with std::move

Tags: c++, c++11

Recently I saw some C++ code similar to this

```
class MyClass {
    public:
    MyClass(std::unique_ptr< MyType > myValue)
        : _myValue(std::move(myValue)) {}

    std::unique_ptr< MyType > _myValue;
};
```

Is this the correct way of initializing a unique_ptr ? Isn't the explicit std::move unnecessary ?

Comment: `myValue` is not a temporary, so `std::move` is required.

Comment: Also, if the caller has a named unique_ptr variable, that will also have to do `MyClass mc{move(p)};` as the argument to the constructor.  This tiny bit of extra verbosity is a good thing, in my opinion, for using unique_ptr.

Comment: I would change the definition to: 
`MyClass(std::unique_ptr< int >&& myValue)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. If you remove the `move`, compiler will complain that there's no copy constructor in `unique_ptr` and refuse your code.